# View [.] not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have an error when displaying the home page, I used foreach to display two tables but when I added the third i just found this error : View [.] not found.
this is the code Controller :

```
public function  try  () {
    $post =actu::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get(); 
    $ville=Villle::orderBy('Ville','desc')->get();
    $specialité=speec::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    return view ('/',['sp'=>$specialité],['vi'=>$ville],['pub'=>$post]);

}
```

and  added this to the home page :

```
     <form action="{{route('hi')}}" method="get"> 
     <input type="text" class="search-field business" name="rech" value="" placeholder ="Cherchez..">
     <select type="text" class="search-field location" name="spec" id="s" value="spec" placeholder ="Spécialités">
     <option selected></option>
   @foreach($sp as $ss)
    <option value=" {{$ss->Spécialité}}"> {{$ss->Spécialité}}</option>
   @endforeach
    </select>
     <select type="text" class="search-field location" name="Région" value="Région" placeholder ="Région">
      <option selected></option>
      @foreach($vi as $vv)
      <option value="{{$vv->Ville}}">{{$vv->Ville}}</option>
       @endforeach
       </select>
        <button class="search-btn" type="submit" id="search"> Recherche </button>

    </form>
    <section>
           @foreach($pub as $p)
                                 <h1> {{$p->Titre}}</h1> 
                                 <h3> {{$p->Contenu}}</h3>
                                 <h3> {{$p->Photo}}</h3>
                                 @endforeach
```

And this is the route :

```
 Route::get('/','Specialite@try');
```

please how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: The view needs to reference a template file, not a path.

Comment: If that `.blade.php` is called `home.blade.php`, the view code would be `return view('home', ...);`

Comment: Go back to Laravel Documentation and see how to create a view and how to use it. The documentation is clear and should be your first source of truth. https://laravel.com/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your view file is in here : directory/view.blade.php

Then your controller should be like this:

```
public function  try  () {
    $post =actu::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get(); 
    $ville=Villle::orderBy('Ville','desc')->get();
    $specialité=speec::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    return view ('directory.view',[
          'sp'=>$specialité,
          'vi'=>$ville],
          'pub'=>$post
    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Assumption

1) You name the html file as `home.blade.php` over this path 
`resoursces/views/home.blade.php`

#### Problem

view() should contain template blade file name(home) and not the path ('/')

```
public function  try  () {
    $post =actu::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get(); 
    $ville=Villle::orderBy('Ville','desc')->get();
    $specialité=speec::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    return view ('/',['sp'=>$specialité],['vi'=>$ville],['pub'=>$post]);
}
```

#### Solutions

Replace the '/' to 'home'

```
public function  try  () {
    $post =actu::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get(); 
    $ville=Villle::orderBy('Ville','desc')->get();
    $specialité=speec::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    return view ('home',['sp'=>$specialité],['vi'=>$ville],['pub'=>$post]);
}
```